# Can Microsoft's Surface 2 run Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-rt

I saw a Surface 2 in a shop yesterday and was blown away by the hardware. The device looks fantastic. However, I'd like to use it to write software while I'm on the move. In particular, I'd like to write ARM assembler and an ARM JIT and a new [HLVM](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/hlvm/) so I want a Surface 2 and not a Surface Pro 2 (which uses an Intel CPU).

Can the Surface 2 run Visual Studio? If not, can it run any IDE that would let me develop code on the device?

Answer (score 4):

It can't run VS. You would need Surface Pro 2 for that.
Not exactly what you are looking for, but there is Visual Studio Online:
http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs

I haven't tried it yet, but may help you.

Comment: Thanks but I really want the device for coding on my commute. So I won't have net access.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no version of VS that can run on an ARM core.  The device also won't permit installing and running desktop apps, only Store apps are supported.  There is no programming IDE in the Store.  You'll need the Pro version.

Comment: Wow, is there any reason why there is no IDE in the Windows Store? Apple prohibit them. Android has at least the AIDE app.

Comment: Same reason that Office is not a Store app.  Hard to operate with fat fingers.  And a sandbox that's too restrictive to write a compiler and debugger.

Comment: Interesting. FWIW, Android's AIDE app has millions of users https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en

Comment: Hmm, millions of programmers, that ought to be close to all of them.  Includes my mom though, she clicks on anything that's free :)